# QuickCheck unresolved dependency while installing Haskell Platform from source

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal, platform

I'm trying to install Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0, but running platform.sh script gives me dependency error, which I am not able to resolve. Error message is:

cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: alex-3.1.3 (user goal)
next goal: QuickCheck (dependency of alex-3.1.3)
rejecting: QuickCheck-2.7.6 (global constraint requires ==2.6)

I tried to ghc-pkg unregister QuickCheck-2.7.6 and cabal install QuickCheck-2.6, but it still fails due to same reason. Besides that I tried to install alex-3.1.3 manually and when that failed too I cleared all packages from my home directory.

I have Haskell Platform 2013 installed but I also installed Cabal 1.18 manually.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Installing the HP should use the cabal which comes with that HP. The cabal you have on your path is likely interfering with that.

Comment: According to documentation cabal 1.18 should be ok for this HP. That's why I installed it. Or was HP installation script supposed to make new cabal installation?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched a web and StackOverflow a bit just to find out that HP installation script is broken on many systems. Eventually I gave up on installing whole HP and went for newest binary distribution of GHC and Cabal which seems to be the simplest way of getting most recent Haskell for my Linux.